# Automapper not apply configuration for new instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I have this configuration for automapper

```
public class Mapping : Profile
{
    public Mapping()
    {
        CreateMap<User, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```

I'm using .net core so my Startup has

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

My controller with constructor

```
public Controller(DbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

Then I have some code to copy users. Here I try to map excising user to new instance except `Id` property and save to database.

```
User user = await _dbContext.Users.FindAsync(id);
User newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(user);
await _dbContext.Users.AddAsync(newUser);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The problem is that configuration for `Id` property doesn't work. I got `newUser` with `Id` of existing user. Why didn't the property ignored?

**User.cs**

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public User(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found that this code works fine

```
var newUser = new User();
_mapper.Map<User, User>(user, newUser);
```

Bu why I can't use `User newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(user);`?

From execution plan

```
$id = .Block(System.Int32 $resolvedValue) {
                    $resolvedValue = .If (
                        $src == null || False
                    ) {
                        .Default(System.Int32)
                    } .Else {
                        $src.Id
                    };
                    $resolvedValue
                };
```

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu and how can it help me?

Comment: It seems to me that you're missing some step and your config is not used.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu But why in this case `_mapper.Map<User, User>(user, newUser);` everything works fine?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with `AutoMapper 7.0.1` and `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection  Version 5.0.1`, it works with `User newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(user);` which set `Id` as `0`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks. see my update. I've add code from execution plan for that property

Comment: So I was wrong, your mapping is applied, because self mapping would be a no-op otherwise, but see @TaoZhou's comment.